# Where do I find the Libraries Tab in Lightning Experience?

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, libraries

Where do I find the Libraries tab in Lightning Experience?

[image]

The only thing I've found so far is the Files tab:

[image]

It has a section Libraries, but it's pretty much useless, since no Libraries can be created there.

Is this one of those features which are currently only available in Aloha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right currently we can only create folder in Library.

As per Salesforce docs:

> To create libraries, switch to Salesforce Classic.

Currently supported functionality in Lightning

[image]

[Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_files_library_folders.htm&type=0)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation does mention [whats possible and whats not](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_files_library_folders.htm&type=0) with Libraries .

Screenshot from the docs

[image]

> Clearly as of now one cannot create,edit and delete libraires from lightning experience .Use aloha experience and also there is no roadmap listed around this functionality .